# Undo a git am --abort

Tags: git

I think I'm hosed, but is there anyway to undo a `git am --abort`

I was using `am` and there were some conflicts (as expected), I resolved these conflicts but instead of doing `git am --continue` I simply committed as normal. Then when I came back later I noticed I was still in am mode but instead of doing `git am --skip` I did `git am --abort` and now my commit is gone.

I could of course go through the process again, but I'd rather not perform the conflict resolution again.

**EDIT:** I resolved my particular issue, but I am still curious if a more robust solution exists. I.e. undo the abort even if the patch was long gone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out git remembered my conflict resolution. The "fix" was as simple as re-running the am command. YMMV I doubt this will work in all situations.

EDIT: `git reflog` as torek suggested also works.

Comment: You must have `rerere` turned on.  If you didn't, any added blobs or finished commits are still findable until garbage collection, but using rerere is a lot easier! :-)

Comment: Maybe I didn't look hard enough, where would I find finished commits in this case?

Comment: Nevermind I see what you are saying, and I do have rerere turned on. How would I find them if I didin't?

Comment: I'm not sure off-hand if they'll be in a reflog.  If they are, "in a reflog" (`git reflog` will show the ones for `HEAD` and they would likely be in there).  If they're not in reflogs, `git fsck --lost-found` will drop commit and blob IDs into `.git/lost-found/`; see the git fsck documentation.

Comment: Thank you so much. I almost lost two hours of work because my branch got in this weird state where it was doing a rebase but wouldn't proceed. I had to abandon the rebase which got rid of all my changes. I'm very happy this command is available in git.